# How to anchor a component with prop?

Tags: reactjs

I have a website that I used fixed menu options to anchor to the place I wanted ,below is a simple structure to demonstrate

mypage.jsx

```js
<div className="mywork">
        <TopbarWork menuOpen={menuOpen} setMenuOpen={setMenuOpen}/>
        <MenuWork menuOpen={menuOpen} setMenuOpen={setMenuOpen}/> 
        <div className="sections">
          <Product />  //origin 
          <Story workData={workData}/> //what I want to achieve
          <Userflow workData = {workData}/>
          <System workData={workData}/>
          <FinalDesign workData={workData}/> 
          
        </div>
      </div>
```

menu.jsx(click to go to the different anchors)

```js
import './menu.scss'
export default function Menu({menuOpen,setMenuOpen}) {
    return (
        <div className={"menu " +  (menuOpen && "active")}>
            <ul>
                <li onClick={()=>setMenuOpen(false)}>
                    <a href="/">Back</a>
                </li>
                <li onClick={()=>setMenuOpen(false)}>
                    <a href="#product">product</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Product.jsx(one of the components)

```js
import { CheckCircle } from '@material-ui/icons';
import './product.scss'

export default function Product({workData}) {
    return (
        <div className="product" id="product"> //important
            <div className="productLeft">
                <div className="productIntro">
                    <p className="title">
                        {workData.title}
                    </p>
                    <p className="desc">
                        {workData.desc}
                    </p>
                    {workData.featured.map((feature)=>{
                        return(
                            <div className="featured">
                                <CheckCircle className="featuredIcon"/>
                                    {feature.title}
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="productRight">
                <div className="item">
                    <img src="assets/desktop.jpeg" alt="" className="desktopImg" />
                    <img src={workData.productImg} alt="" className="productImg" />
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    )
}
```

So right now the problem is I have to pass "workData"  into components , but after that if I click on the anchor, it would show **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'workData')** , I assume that I have to pass the workData too when I click on the anchor ?
But what's the right way to do that ?

EDIT

I tried using Link and history (react-router-dom) but  failed , here's my code

menu.jsx

```js
export default function MenuWork({menuOpen,setMenuOpen,workData}) {
    console.log(workData)
    const history = useHistory();
    const handleClick = ()=>{
        setMenuOpen(false)
        history.push({
            pathname:'/mywork#userflow',
            state: { workData:workData}
        })
    }
    return (
        <div className={"menu " +  (menuOpen && "active")}>
            <ul>
            <li onClick={()=>setMenuOpen(false)}>
                    <a href="/">Back</a>
                </li>
                <li onClick={()=>setMenuOpen(false)}>
                    <Link to="#product">Product</Link>
                </li>
                <li onClick={()=>setMenuOpen(false)}>
                    <Link to={{
                        pathname:"/mywork#story",
                        state:{ workData:workData}
                    }}>Story</Link>
                </li>
                <li onClick={()=>handleClick()}>
                    userflow
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

If I use Link and pass the state, it will return blank page without loading anything, and If I don't pass any state with Link , it will shows the same error as above.

Comment: Try replacing the `a` element with the `Link` component https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link . it should persist the `workData` which I believe u r using bcuz of the reload effect of `a` element navigation.

Comment: @SultanH. It sill shows **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'workData') **, I even tried to pass the same state using Link , but it will become blank page  without anything being loaded